# "Unimplemented Code" error message in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling

Has anyone seen an "Unimplemented Code" error before in Qt?

I'm trying to open a pkcs12 file in Qt with the following code:

```
QByteArray password="1234";
QString f="/Users/test/Desktop/certs/new.pfx";
QFile pkcs(f);
QFileInfo fileinfo(pkcs);
pkcs.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QSslKey key;
QSslCertificate cert;
QList<QSslCertificate> imported_certs;
static bool import=QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(&pkcs,&key,&cert,&imported_certs,password);
pkcs.close();
```

And the error i'm getting is just:

```
 "Unimplemented Code"
```

I'm using the Qt version 5.7.0

The code above is implemented in a class constructor; upon running the program to create an instance of the class the "Unimplemented Code" error appears in the console (this is a **Qt console application**, with GUI disabled).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: As the error suggests, you are calling a function that is stubbed out in Qt source code and the Q_UNIMPLEMENTED error code is being returned.  We don't know what version of Qt you are using so we can't say for sure what you are trying to do that is not supported.

Comment: @ChrisStathis I've edited my question

Comment: You're "getting" an error. Where do you get the error from? Does it just appear on the console? Do you get it as a result from a call?

Comment: @KubaOber This error appears in the console, the code above is implemented in a constructor and appears in the console when I run the program to create an instance of the class object...

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate that.

Comment: Try debugging your program by stepping over, and see where is the error from